# Lotus Domino Designer crash and project corruption

Tags: java, project, xpages, lotus-domino

Every time Lotus Domino Designer crash, if i have a database opened that contains java classes deployed into **WebContent/WEB-INF/src**, and/or jars included into **Java build path**, i always need to add jars again, and to re-deploy classes using *Build path -> Use as source folder*.

It seems a project corruption.

Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: Honestly, try to figure out what crashes your designer so often it bothers you. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812148/why-is-build-time-of-local-application-affected-by-network/15817032#15817032

Comment: Not so often, just a couple of times. But same problem..

Comment: I will suggest a complete re-install of Domino Designer where you restore your data and settings afterwards. See this post on how to export/import your settings: http://www.intec.co.uk/quick-setup-restore-of-domino-designer/

Comment: Did you increase jvm.properties settings already to avoid crashes http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21617708?

Comment: I've seen that issue lots of times too: the build path just seems to be restored to the default. I didn't relate it to a Designer crash, but it might be that that's the cause. I'll keep an eye out for it. In the mean while this is just one of the first things I check when an application doesn't work or when I prepare it for production.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it's just the same pattern i follow..